# Does "So do I" reflect a mirrored perspective or a direct perspective?

Tags: meaning

For example, if I was to say "*I love you*", and someone responds with "*so do I*", would their response, from a solely grammatical point of view reflect that they too, love themselves, or would it mirror the perspective to mean "I love you too"?

Comment: It's ambiguous. Though, in context, it's normally not intended to be a joke.

Comment: “Does "So do I" reflect a mirrored perspective or a direct perspective?” — Yes.

Comment: In my idiolect, "so do I" is the same as "I do too" and would mean I love myself as well.  In context, I would take it as a lazy way of saying "I love you too" or a joke, but would find the phrasing slightly jolting.